# what does it mean by recode(x,y) in R

Tags: r, function, recode

I am reading other's code but not get the recode part

function (x){recode(x,5})-1

All the previous recode codes included = sign to give something some value, I don't understand what here the "5" mean. thank you!

Comment: When asking a question about a function that is not in the base packages, you should include a `library` call to load whatever package your function comes from.

Comment: It seems to me that : 

    function (x){recode(x,5})-1

is bad / unworking code : the brackets are not closed and parenthesis not opened. Are you sure the code you copy and paste is working ? Can you provide a larger sample of the code ?

Comment: Maybe reading `?dplyr::recode` could help you. But this code is certainly wrong.